Sequential Criterion in Metric Spaces
I am taking a course at the moment on metric spaces. I am wanting some clarification on the sequential criterion over metric spaces.
We are told that if $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, $V\subset X$, $a$ is a limit point of $V$, $f:V\rightarrow Y$ is a function and $\ell \in Y$, then the following are equivalent

$f(x)\rightarrow \ell$ as $x\rightarrow a$
For any sequence $(x_n)$ in $V\setminus \left\{a\right\}$ converging to $a$,$f(x_n)\rightarrow \ell$

But it was my understanding that for a sequence in a metric space to converge to a limit, the limit has to be included in the metric space. I thought this was the case because people online give this as the reason why $$\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$ is Cauchy but not convergent.
Obviously my intuition somewhere is wrong, just need some help identifying which concept I am not properly grasping.

Could you cite the exact theorem? Point 1. and 2. are not very clear. What is $f$, what are $V$ and $a$? Where do $\ell$ and $f(x)$  live etc.

@Gribouillis have edited the question to give the conditions we are told

Your objection is not relevant because the limit $\ell$ belongs to the metric space $Y$. On the other hand I don't think the theorem is true because if $a\in V$ and $f(a)\not = \ell$, point 2. may hold when point 1. is false.

Sorry @Gribouillis my confusion was with the statement for any sequence in $V\setminus \left{ a\right}$ converging to $a$. I was not sure how the sequence can converge to a point not contained in the set?

Take the example $V=X = Y = {\mathbb R}$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ when $x\not = 0$. Let $a=0$ and $\ell=1$. Condition 2 is met but not condition 1.

I think there is a typo. It should be "$a$ is a limit point of $V$"

@Vit thanks. Have fixed the typo

Yeah, so $a\in X$, and everything is fine. This is theorem 4.2 in Rudin's 'Principles of Mathematical Analysis' you can check there if you need a proof.

Thanks @Vit ! Reading these pages in Rudin was helpful.
